# Sharding state recovery process found document - contains wrong list of config servers

Tags: mongodb

I've been stuck on this issue for the most part of the day, feel like I am hitting a wall. I hope someone more knowledgeable can help me.

**Historical Setup**

- Mongo Shard (4x replica sets)
- Config Servers (3x)
- Mongos (2x)

This setup got migrated to a different DC. Process involved setting up servers in new DC, connecting them as members and subsequently shutting down instances in the original DC.

Migration got completed successfully, without any issues.

**The Problem**

From time to time, Mongo instance fails to start as it is trying to connect to config servers in the OLD DC.

Log line from mongod:

```
SHARDING [rsSync] Sharding state recovery process found document { _id: "minOpTimeRecovery", configsvrConnectionString: "config_cluster/mongo-config-1:27017,mongo-config-2:27017,mongo-config-3:27017", shardName: "shard_cluster", minOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1536309187000|2, t: 26457 }, minOpTimeUpdaters: 1 }
```

Problem is, those mongo-config-1, mongo-config-2 and mongo-config-3 are domains from OLD DC. They are not in the new Mongos instance's config file.

I've found the following entries in Mongo PRIMARY's *db.system.version*

> { "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 5 }
>
> { "_id" : "minOpTimeRecovery", "configsvrConnectionString" : "config_cluster/mongo-config-1:27017,mongo-config-2:27017,mongo-config-3:27017", "shardName" : "shard_cluster", "minOpTime" : { "ts" : Timestamp(1536309187, 2), "t" : NumberLong(26457) }, "minOpTimeUpdaters" : 1 }

My question is:

- Is it safe to delete {"_id": "minOpTimeRecovery"} document?
- If not, what is the safest way to resolve this?

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: It's 3.2.22, haven't had a chance to upgrade yet.

Answer (score 0):

As per below documentation you can delete the document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/#remove-the-minoptimerecovery-document-from-the-admin-system-versions-collection

Comment: This may or may not be a good/correct answer, however link only solutions are discouraged here (link rot...). You could perhaps expand on it a bit by, for example, quoting the part of the link that solves the OP's problem? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)